# Accordion Menu in XCODE

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit, accordion

hey, I'm trying to make a accordion menu in Objective-C for a iPad app. The only thing I know is that I should look over core animation. 
Couldn't find anything helpfull. 
Can anyone help me ? at least give me a few pointers.

Comment: Please describe more specifically what you want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am also trying to implement Accordion Menu for iPad.. i have been doing some research and found that this link is a good help...
http://www.deepinthecouch.com/iphone-sdk/accordion-uitableviews-programming-backwards

[(Go here for the archived version)](http://web.archive.org/web/20101107132334/http://www.deepinthecouch.com/iphone-sdk/accordion-uitableviews-programming-backwards)

i have tried putting in the codes in this blog to my project, but i kept getting some weird errors..

so instead, i am taking the concept and try to implement something myself...

if u get ur accordion menu work, do share it.. i will do the same... :)

[Update] : i have revisited the blog page again just now, and found that the author have added a new entry and added a piece of code that works...

Have a look

http://www.deepinthecouch.com/iphone-sdk/accordion-uitableviews

Comment: I've done it without using core animation. I just made 3 views and animated them to get bigger or smaller.